# Is it ethically alright to submit an extended version of work that will be presented in a demo session to the main conference at a different venue?

Tags: publications, ethics

We will soon present our work as part of the demo sessions at a conference. However, since being accepted for the presentation, we have significantly improved the existing work, to the point that it can be the subject of a main conference submission.

I was wondering if it was ethically/professionally alright to submit the extended work to a different conference *before* the demo presentation?

Comment: Have you considered to approach the conference that you will give the demo session at and see if they want to do something with the extended work instead of the demo?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that for a demo session you have given up any rights, but you should check that.

But yes, you can always present extended versions anywhere you like, though you may be required, ethically and legally, to cite the original rather than just including it in the new work.

Note that the extended version will almost certainly appear after the demo session so you are just citing prior work.

An additional complication arises if the "demo" produces a written "paper" - a "publication". If it does not, then what you are really demoing is (part of) the work that will appear elsewhere. Then the newer work is appearing for the first time, other than orally, so the first time it leaves a written record. In that case you have more freedom to just incorporate the old in to the new.

But, ask yourself first whether the demo session is a "publication" or not. If it is, cite it.